# Releasing a service after being resolved

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle windsor on my project. I want to make lazy resolve services and repositories.The sample codes :

```
public IPersonService PersonService
    {
        get { return _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPersonService>(); }
        set { _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPersonService>(value); }
    }

    public ICityService CityService
    {
        get { return _windsorContainer.Resolve<ICityService>(); }
        set { _windsorContainer.Resolve<ICityService>(value); }
    }

    public IPhoneService PhoneService
    {
        get { return _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPhoneService>(); }
        set { _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPhoneService>(value); }
    }
```

The question is: When resolved is over, how to I need to do, release these.
Tnx

---

**Edit**

My Roof Class is :

```
public class PhonebookApplication
{
    public WindsorContainer _windsorContainer;

    private void InitializeWindsor()
    {
        _windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        _windsorContainer.Install(Configuration.FromXmlFile("Castle.config"));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_windsorContainer != null)
        {
            _windsorContainer.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<PhonebookApplication> s_Current = new Lazy<PhonebookApplication>(() => new PhonebookApplication(), true);

    public static PhonebookApplication Current
    {
        get { return s_Current.Value; }
    }

    public void ApplicationStart()
    {
        InitializeWindsor();
    }


    //Service count increaseble as your have.
    public IPersonService PersonService
    {
        get { return _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPersonService>(); }
        set { _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPersonService>(value); }
    }

    public ICityService CityService
    {
        get { return _windsorContainer.Resolve<ICityService>(); }
        set { _windsorContainer.Resolve<ICityService>(value); }
    }

    public IPhoneService PhoneService
    {
        get { return _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPhoneService>(); }
        set { _windsorContainer.Resolve<IPhoneService>(value); }
    }
}
```

}

And If I want to invoke a method on a HomeController, I use method as `PhoneBookApplication.Current.PhoneService.GetAllList()` , then I want to call release current resolved service, when after the method invoke is finished. If I inject this class constructor all factory classes, roof class is depends on thus, therefore  I dont want using ctor inject anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this - you can use Windsors `TypedFactory` faclity instead to resolve and release components at runtime.

You just create an interface:

```
public interface IPersonServiceFactory
{
    IPersonService Create();

    void Release(IPersonService svc);
}
```

Then register `AsFactory`

```
container.Register(Component.For<IPersonServiceFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Then inject the factory into your class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(IPersonServiceFactory personServiceFactory)
    {
        IPersonService svc = personServiceFactory.Create();

        // Do some work with the service
        svc.Blah();

        // Now release it
        personServiceFactory.Release(svc);
    }
}
```

You need to make sure you've added type `TypedFactoryFacility` to the container in your bootstrapping code:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

**Addendum:**

You can also create a custom resolver for the factory interface if you need to add any special resolution logic:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IPersonServiceFactory>().AsFactory(x => x.SelectedWith<PersonServiceFactoryComponentSelector>()));
```

Don't forget to register it too

```
container.Register(Component.For<PersonServiceFactoryComponentSelector>());
```

The implementation should subclass `DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector` and can override methods to resolve the component name

e.g. you might want to add a parameter to the `Create()` factory method so that it takes a bool `Create(bool useAlternateComponent)` which determines whether to use one component or another:

```
public class DispatcherFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if(arguments[0] is bool && (bool)arguments[0] == true)
        // Return a certain component name
        else
        // Return a different component name
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,your answer is my partial answer,This situtation,If i want to run a method then I depends on inject "IPersonServiceFactory personServiceFactory", but I dont want access a method with injection, I want to access methods by a static roof class. Roof.PersonService.Blah() etc.. How can I implement factory without injection.

Comment: Hi, Can I implement the factory as an Interceptor ?

Comment: Not sure how your interceptor would work here, you have to consider what would trigger the interceptor to release the component. I suppose you could make sure all your interfaces inherit `IDisposable` and let the interceptor release the component when it's disposed method is called. Is there any reason you don't want to inject factories? You can release components using `container.Release()` is the question more about how to get the components to auto-release? Are your components registered as Transient? Can you give more background on the actual application?

Comment: Question is as your saying: I want to develope auto-release for each methods after invoked. I have used **transient** and **singleton**.

Comment: You don't need to release singletons - they last the lifetime of the container, but since you are using MVC, why don't you just use `LifestylePerWebRequest` for your components? Windsor will automatically manage resolved lifestyles when the web request ends - not sure what you are gaining by not using injection either